# How can I use a dynamic database name in SQL for my vb.net app?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I need to run the below script from my vb.net app & would like to know how would I make the database name (mynewdatabase_db) a parameter?

Basically I need to run this script on certain databases so I need the database name to be dynamic.

```
    Dim MySqlQuery2 As String = "USE mynewdatabase_db " & _
        "TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable " & _
        " " & _
        "INSERT INTO MyTable ([MyNumber], [HTTPAlias]) VALUES (0, @MyDomainAlias1) " & _
        "INSERT INTO MyTable ([MyNumber], [HTTPAlias]) VALUES (0, @MyDomainAlias2) " & _
        "INSERT INTO MyTable ([MyNumber], [HTTPAlias]) VALUES (0, @MyDomainAlias3) "

    Using cmd2 = New SqlCommand(MySqlQuery2.ToString, myConnection)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias1", MyDomainName)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias2", "www." & MyDomainName)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias3", MyDomainName & "." & MyTempDomainName)
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it part of your connection string(s). That way it wouldn't be hard coded into your application.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks. I did my first sql command, closed the database connection then opened up a new database connection & did my second sql command.. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very usefull class named [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Supposing you have a initial connection string stored in your app.config or web.config.
Then you could write a method like this, which load your stored connection string and
change the Initial Catalog to a new one passed as parameter

```
Public Function GetNewConnectionString(newDataName as String) as String
    Dim cnnString as String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnName"].ConnectionString
    Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnnString);
    builder.InitialCatalog = newDataName
    return builder.ConnectionString
End Function
```

You could change your connection string calling this method and then executing the query above dropping the part that try to use a different database.

```
Using myConnection = new SqlConnection(GetNewConnectionString("mynewdatabase-db"))
Using cmd2 = New SqlCommand(MySqlQuery2.ToString, myConnection)     
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias1", MyDomainName)     
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias2", "www." & MyDomainName)     
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDomainAlias3", MyDomainName & "." & MyTempDomainName)     
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()     
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - I appreciate it! FYI: I didn't delete the table in my query, I deleted it's contents.

Comment: Oh yes a bit confused. Time to go to bed.